# How to remove the spaces besides hiphen in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am getting the image names from mysql database. I have my images containing two to three words with png extension. Also the names contains hiphen symbol. First I want to remove the 
space to the left and right of the hiphen symbol. Secondly, I want to replace the space between two words with underscore symbol. How can I write the query for this?

For second one:

UPDATE table_name set colname=replace(colname, ' ', '')

Please help me with the query for first task...
Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to update the table with these changes or just have them while SELECT

Comment: *an example is better than perception*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could use a few `REPLACE`

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        name,
        ' -',
        '-'
      ),
      '- ',
      '-'
    ),
    ' ',
    '_'
  ) as new_name
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'e using strings to hold structured data, which is not an efficient use of a relational database management system like MySQL: you would be better to alter your schema so that each discrete data unit is in its own column (and you can then rebuild your desired strings on retrieving the data from the database).

However, in answer to your specific questions, it isn't clear exactly what you want:

- If you want to remove at most one space on either side of multiple hyphens, then [Puggan Se's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11373783/623041) is the one for you.
- If you want to remove exactly one space on either side of multiple hyphens, then the same answer can be simplified a tad:

  ```
  REPLACE(REPLACE(colname, ' - ', '-'), ' ', '_')
  ```
- If you want to remove multiple spaces on either side of a single hyphen, you would be better to split the string using MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function and then trim the results:

  ```
  REPLACE(CONCAT(
    RTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(colname, '-',  1)),
    '-',
    LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(colname, '-', -1))
  ), ' ', '_')
  ```
- If you want to remove multiple spaces on either side of multiple hyphens, you will need to create a function that loops over your string:

  ```
  DELIMITER ;;

  CREATE FUNCTION trim_delim (
      IN input TEXT
    , IN delim CHAR(1)
  )
  RETURNS TEXT
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE i      INT DEFAULT 1 ;
    DECLARE result TEXT;

    WHILE CHAR_LENGTH(input) > 0 AND cur_position > 0 DO
      SET i      := INSTR(input, delim);

      SET result := CONCAT(
        IF(CHAR_LENGTH(result) > 0, CONCAT(result, delim), ''),
        IF(i, RTRIM(LEFT(input, i - 1)), input)
      );

      SET input  := LTRIM(SUBSTRING(input, i + 1));
    END WHILE;

    RETURN result;
  END;;

  DELIMITER ;
  ```

  You could then use this function thus:

  ```
  REPLACE(trim_delim(colname, '-'), ' ', '_')
  ```